# Compartir archivo mp4 generado por mi app a redes sociales. share intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app

Necesito compartir mi archivo de video mp4 generado por mi app, el cual adquiere nombre con un (`System.currentTimeMillis /1000`). la acción compartir debe escoger ese ultimo archivo generado para compartirlo en redes sociales.

Dejo el método `initRecorder` el cual genera el archivo mp4 y el metodo `compartir` actual.

```
private final String MAIN_FOLDER = "DCApp/";

private final String RUTA_VIDEO = MAIN_FOLDER + "DCvideos";

private void initRecorder(){

        String videoName = "DC_" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) + ".mp4";
        File fileVideo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), VIDEO_RUTE);

        try{

            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileVideo + videoName);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

---

Método compartir:

```
 private void share() {

    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    share.setType("video/");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share via:"));
}
```

Comment: Estimo que la solución seria `share.setType("video/*");` o `share.setType("video/mp4");` estoy un poco olvidado del tema. Has probado así? y con `share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);` en lugar de `ACTION_PICK`

Comment: @FedericoMadoery gracias por el comentario será de utilidad, ahora mi sgte duda sería: como lo realizo correctamente para que el capture el archivo mp4 que acaba de generar la pp y no y no un archivo vacíó

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta lo comentado y lo que me consultaste, mas algo de documentación oficial leída, tomaría el siguiente camino:

```
private void share(String videoName ) {

        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("video/mp4"); // Configuras el tipo de archivo

        // Tomas el archivo desde la ruta de guardado, para que no haya error
        File fileToShare = new File(RUTA_VIDEO + videoName ); 
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileToShare);

        //Agregas la uri del video que deseas enviar, esto se puede usar para cualquier archivo.
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartilo!"));
}
```

> Deberias enviar el nombre de archivo como parametro.